# How to filter data using an function? - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'am trying to so something simple, just use a function to call loc from pandas and then print it in an excell sheet, but I don't know why the output is empty.

```
def update_output(farol,dias,prod,officer,anal,coord):
    df_f=df.loc[(df['FarolAging'].isin([farol])) & (df['Dias Pendentes'].isin([dias])) & (df['Produto'].isin([prod])) & (df['Officer'].isin([officer])) & (df['Analista'].isin([anal])) & (df['Coordenador'].isin([coord]))]
    df_f.to_excel('C:\\Users\\brechtl\\Downloads\\File.xlsx', index=False)

update_output('vermelho', 'Até 20 dias','','Alexandre Denardi','Guilherme De Oliveira Moura','Anna Claudia')
```

Edit:
As asked by a friend at the comments, I created a similar dataframe as the one I'am using

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["Vermelho","Verde","Amarelo"],["20 dias","40 dias","60 dias"],["Prod1","Prod1","Prod2"],
["Alexandre Denardi","Alexandre Denardi","Lucas Fernandes"],["Guilherme De Oliveira Moura","Leonardo Silva","Julio Cesar"],
["Anna Claudia","Bruno","Bruno"]]), columns=["FarolAging","Dias Pendentes","Produto","Officer","Analista","Coord"])
```

Comment: It would seem that `df_f` is an empty DataFrame because your `.loc` condition is False. It would be useful if you provided a sample of `df` where the various conditions are all True.

Comment: add one more parenthesis at the end `...[cord])))]`

Comment: @user19077881 I added a sample from my df

Comment: You are producing an empty dataframe because not all the conditions are True. If you use `print(df_f)` within the function you will see this.

Comment: I did it, it's because of the third parameter, right? So, how can I do it? My idea was to call this function with a filter, and then type the values. I thought that if one parameter was empty, `.loc` would undestand in a way to bring all the data from that column, as if it wasn't necessary to filter that column specifically

Comment: Yes it's the empty string causing the issue. The & combined conditions each produce True or False so if any are False then the whole selection fails. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed value for third parameter while calling function.
Is it by mistake or intentional? This could result in NO data, as all filter conditions are in "AND", means all must be true.

Comment: It was intentional.

My ideia is a function that can make this huge filter. I thought that if one parameter is empty like that, it would undestand to show all the values from that column. I'm not sure if I made myself clear, but thats what i'am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

On the basis that you want to want to have optional values passed to the function then I think you need to use a function within the selection. The model code below shows how this might work (using == for the comparison).

Using the example DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["aa", "bb", "cc"], "col2": ["dd", "ee", "ff"]})

def test(row, val1, val2):
    if val1 == '':
        val1 = row['col1']
    if val2 == '':
       val1 = row['col2']
    if row['col1'] == val1 and row['col2'] == val2:
        return True
    else: 
        return False
    
def func(x1, x2):
    df_f = df.loc[df.apply((lambda x: test(x, x1, x2)), axis = 1)]
    return df_f


print(func('', 'dd'))
```

gives

```
  col1 col2
0   aa   dd

print(func('aa', 'dd'))
```

gives

```
  col1 col2
0   aa   dd

print(func('xx', 'dd'))
```

gives empty dataframe

Comment: I was trying this way because em other moments, the third column may needs to be used, just as the 5th and 6th column may not. Is there any other way? Ow I would need to create this filter with conditions?

Comment: I have modified my answer to suggest how optional column values might be coded. I hope this helps.